waiting in javascript context using dart
the goal is to be able to wait for dart code to process and receive its output in the javascript context but i am not being able to.
I am not able to wait with dart:js (code1).
I am able to wait using flutter_js(code2) .
the issue with flutter_js is that it does not work with flutter web.
is is possible to wait with dart:js or another package that works with flutter web?
i found this stack overflow that is similar ::
How to asynchronously call JavaScript in Flutter?
How to get callback or return value from async JS function to Dart in Flutter Web?
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/50530
the second and third link were exatactly what i was looking for a think but i dont understand what the answer was.
any help is greatly appreciated it/
code1::
import 'dart:js';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'dart:js' as js;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class JsCompilerUtil {
  Future<bool?> process_client_script({
    required String script,
    required Map<String, dynamic> current,
  }) async {
    js.JsObject jsObject = js.JsObject.jsify(current);
    js.context['c'] = jsObject;

    // js.context['c'] = current;
    var result = js.context.callMethod("eval", [script]);

    return result;
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  JsCompilerUtil jsCompilerUtil = JsCompilerUtil();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _initialize_data();
  }

  Future<void> _initialize_data() async {
    String script = """
console.log("Hi from js, this is the inputed name: "+c.name);
var res = c.dummyWait();
console.log("res:")
""";

    Map<String, dynamic> current = {
      "name": "Juan",
      "dummyWait": dummyWait
    };

    final res = await jsCompilerUtil.process_client_script(script: script, current: current);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox();
  }

  Future<String> dummyWait() async {
    print("dummyWait()\n");
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    return 'MESSAGE FROM DART';
  }
}

output of code1::
Restarted application in 28ms.
The debugEmulateFlutterTesterEnvironment getter is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use `debugEmulateFlutterTesterEnvironment` from `dart:ui_web` instead.
Hi from js, this is the inputed name: Juan
dummyWait()
res:

code2:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_js/flutter_js.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late JavascriptRuntime flutterJs;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    flutterJs = getJavascriptRuntime();
    _setupJavaScriptBridge();
  }

  void _setupJavaScriptBridge() {
    flutterJs.onMessage('dummyAwait', (args) async {
      String result = await dummyAwaitFunction();
      return result;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('JavaScript in Dart'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: _logic,
          child: Text('Run JavaScript'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _logic() async {
    String result = await runJavaScript();
    print("JavaScript result: $result");
  }

  Future<String> runJavaScript() async {
    // Dart map
    final current = {"name": "juan"};

    // Convert Dart map to JSON string
    String jsonString = jsonEncode(current);

    // JavaScript script to parse JSON string, call Dart function, and print result
    String script = '''
      var current = JSON.parse('$jsonString');
      async function waitForDart() {
        var res = await sendMessage('dummyAwait');
        console.log("INSDE OF JS: " + res);
        return res;
      }
      waitForDart();
    ''';

    // Evaluate JavaScript script
    JsEvalResult jsResult = await flutterJs.evaluateAsync(script);

    return jsResult.stringResult;
  }

  Future<String> dummyAwaitFunction() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    return 'MESSAGE FROM DART';
  }
}



You could try to add a callback to your Dart function, making a function in JS which returns a Promise and resolving that promise when the callback is called, I am not sure exactly how you would go about adding a callback function, but there is likely to be something on Google about it.
